# Transferring domain and web hosting - will office 365 emails still work?

Tags: email, dns, office365, web-hosting

We're currently with 1&1 for our domain registration and web hosting for our website www.forthisexample.co.uk

Office 365 is our email server and all our employees have email address that follow firstname@forthisexample.co.uk set up on our 365 account.

We would like to transfer our domain registration and web hosting to a new company. The domain will obviously be the same www.forthisexample.co.uk but will be registered and the website hosted with the new company.

We have an MX record on 1&1 : forthisexample-co-uk.mail.protection.outlook.com

As the domain name is staying the same, do I need to change anything for the email address to carry on working? or do i just add this MX record on the new web hosting cpanel?

Sorry if the question is vague, not sure how best to ask this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Working of emails is based on MX record only. This specifies a mail server responsible for accepting email messages on behalf of a recipient's domain. So if anyway your nameservers are changed you need to update MX record.
So you only just need to add this MX record on the new web hosting cpanel.

References:[For mx smooth migration](https://www.wireload.net/news/2010/03/how_to_accomplish_a_smooth_email_migration_for_your_domain.html)

[Office 365 dns setup](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-DNS-records-for-Office-365-at-any-DNS-hosting-provider-7b7b075d-79f9-4e37-8a9e-fb60c1d95166)